# Converting $_POST text input into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, input, multidimensional-array

On my online shop, there's a form with a big number of text inputs, representing quantities of products. There are three fields for every product: quantity of product in S size, M size and L size.

So the name of input field must contain both the product id and the size. This is simplified code of the form:

```
foreach ($productid as $id ) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="s'.$id.'" />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="m'.$id.'" />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="l'.$id.'" />';
}
```

I want to process this input sent via $_POST and save all values of all input field into a single multidimensional array. The format of the desired array is as follows:

> $input['32']['m']='20'
>   means that the customer ordered 20x the product of id 32 in size M.

All my tries to do that failed because I don't understand how to loop through $_POST values to turn them into more than a one-dimension array.

Any idea how to process such input and get a two-dimension array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets `[]` will make an array, so try this and `print_r($_POST)` and see:

```
foreach ($productid as $id ) {
    echo '<input type="text" name="product['.$id.'][s]" />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="product['.$id.'][m]" />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="product['.$id.'][l]" />';
}
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays. Note that this works for PHP, but not for JavaScript.